# what do /s ^ $ do in Regex?

Tags: regex, credit-card

so i just learned regex today and we didn't get to these symbols
/s ^ $

the reason im asking is, firstly i want to know, but i was tasked with writing a regex for all active and common credit cards and the issue i was stuck on is that american express cards have 1 digit less. and didn't know how to write the Regex so that only when the first two digits are 37 (which is American express only) a 15 digit total is allowed.

then i found this:

```
^((4\d{3})|(5[1-5]\d{2})|(6011)|(34\d{1})|(37\d{1}))-?\s?\d{4}-?\s?\d{4}-?\s?\d{4}|3[4,7][\d\s-]{15}$
```

and if i take a WORKING CC from Visa lets say (16 digits) and subtract one, it doesn't work, but 15 digits DO WORK with American express, can anyone explain what in the regex does that?

Comment: Did you [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)?

Comment: [Read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php). Break down the regex into its *simplest* parts. Work out what each one does. Don't be intimidated by the mass of line noise in front of you. Nobody can digest the whole thing in one bite. Just break it down and work your way back up from the simplest components.

Comment: Question title and question body don't match at all. Title is about meaning of `\s ^ $` and body is about validating AMEX card #

Comment: qwrrty why is it mistaken? and what does \s- actually mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Regex

```
^((4\d{3})|(5[1-5]\d{2})|(6011)|(34\d{1})|(37\d{1}))-?\s?\d{4}-?\s?\d{4}-?\s?\d{4}|3[4,7][\d\s-]{15}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/1vsUQpFAhYMJpkkp)

http://regex101.com/r/yO2sY0

This will describe your regex to you in the bottom...The issue is that your regex isn't valid...

`^` this is beginging of string
`$` end of string
`\s` matches whitespace (spaces, tabs and new lines). \S is negated \s.

The regex isn't valid because of the following

> Errors are explained from left to right. Move the mouse cursor over them to see the error highlighted in your pattern
>
> -: Can not form ranges with shorthand properties

### Solution

Use the following Regex which is documented here http://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html

```
^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?          # Visa
 |  5[1-5][0-9]{14}                  # MasterCard
 |  3[47][0-9]{13}                   # American Express
 |  3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}   # Diners Club
 |  6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}      # Discover
 |  (?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11}      # JCB
)$
```

### Simplified Regex

```
\b(?:\d[ -]*?){13,16}\b
```

Comment: Could you clarify why the regex isn't valid?

Comment: I think he/she is saying that the supplied regex works but he/she doesn't know why

Comment: @Srb1313711 According to regex101 the regex he provided isn't valid...I will check RegexBuddy when I get to my computer and not this VM i'm on this second.

Comment: I just tried the regex here http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ with some test card details and it worked?

Comment: regex101 complains that you cannot have a character class that ends with a hyphen: `[\d\s-]`. It is mistaken. :-)

Comment: http://regexr.com?37hji didn't work for me.

Comment: added debuggex to show the state machine